# The attaching maps and the characteristic maps of a new CW structure.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I know that the sphere $S^n$ has the structure of a cell complex with just two cells, $e^0$ and $e^n,$ where the $n$- cell being attached by the constant map $S^{n-1} \to e^0.$ I also know that another structure of a cell complex on $S^n$ is with two cells in each dimension I do not know the attaching maps in this case though. Could anyone clarify to me what are the attaching maps in this case?

Now, if I want to show that the circle $S^1$ has a CW structure with n $0$-cells and n $1$- cells and I know that the definition of CW complexes is the pushout of the diagram $$X^{(n - 1)} \leftarrow \sqcup \partial D_{\alpha}^n \rightarrow \sqcup  D_{\alpha}^n.$$ And I know that the CW complex structure can be determined by determining the characteristic maps and once you know them you can determine the attaching maps by restricting its domain to the boundary. How can I determine the characteristic maps in this case? What is the intuition behind that? What are these characteristic maps?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with two points. Connect them along two different paths and you get a circle. Fill in the circle twice (say, with an upper hemisphere and a lower hemisphere), and you get a sphere (2-sphere). Filling in the sphere in two independent ways gets you a 3-sphere, though this is harder to picture as symmetrically (maybe you can imagine filling in the interior of the ball and then filling up the exterior including a point at infinity).

In this structure, you make an $S^{n-1}$ inductively, then you attach two cells $e^n_+$ and $e^n_-$ both along the attaching map $\operatorname{id}\colon S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$, and the result is homeomorphic to $S^n$.

Thinking of $S^n$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, you can think of the two characteristic maps as the embedding of the upper and lower hemispheres (the sets where the final coordinate is positive or negative). The characteristic maps of the non-top-dimensional cells are just the embedding of the lower or upper hemisphere of the equator, or of the equator's equator, and so on.

If you want to be super explicit with $S^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ as an example, the upper hemisphere is embedded as $D^2 \to S^2$ by $(x, y) \mapsto (x, y, \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$, and the lower hemisphere cell is embedded as $(x, y) \mapsto (x, y, -\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$. The two $1$-cells are embedded with maps $[-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ given by $x \mapsto (x, \sqrt{1-x^2}, 0)$ and $x \mapsto (x, -\sqrt{1-x^2}, 0)$.
The $0$-cells are the points $(\pm 1, 0, 0)$.

Comment: Can you please write the attaching maps explicitly in the first part of my question, I just do not know how to write them? Or did you meant that they are just the identity maps?

Comment: I believe your first two paragraphs is an answer to my first question, while your second two paragraphs is an answer to my second question, am I correct?

Comment: So if I want to show that the circle $S^1$ has a CW structure with n $0$-cells and n $1$- cells, how can I show that the pushout is the quotient ?

Comment: My whole response was about making $S^n$ using two cells in each dimension up to $n$. Your question about $S^1$ seems pretty independent, but if you want, you can think of that as dividing the circle into $n$ equal parts (1-cells), and each adjacent pair of 1-cells intersects at a 0-cell. For this, $X^0 = \big\{e^{k2\pi i/n} \ :\ k \in \{0, \dots, n-1\}\big\} \subset S^1$. The attaching maps for these cells are maps $\coprod\partial D^1 \to X^0$, but since $\partial D^1$ is just two points, the whole coproduct is discrete. That's why we can glue a 1-cell between any pair of 0-cells.

Comment: Writing $e^1$ as $[0,1]$ for convenience, the characteristic maps $c_k \colon [0,1] \to S^1$ for what I described above are given by $c_k(t) = \exp(2\pi i (k + t)/n)$. That's just the embedding of the $k$th piece of the circle.

Comment: Also, yes, I did mean the identity maps. So in the inductive construction with two cells in in each dimension you have the pushout of $D^n \sqcup D^n \leftarrow S^{n-1} \sqcup S^{n-1} \rightarrow S^{n-1}$ where the left map is inclusion and the right map is the identity on each summand.

Comment: why adding k to t? Can you clarify what is k and t please?

Comment: when you say coproduct, you mean colimit?

Comment: so the attaching maps in $S^1$ are the projection maps?

Comment: The point $e^{2\pi i \cdot (4.27)/6}$ has $k=4$ and $t=0.27$, and lives in the 1-cell between the 0-cell at $e^{2\pi i \cdot 4/6}$ and the 0-cell at $e^{2\pi i \cdot 5/6}$. The index $k$ just selects which of the $n$ equal parts of the circle we're in, and the $t\in[0,1]$ selects what percentage of the way we are along that part.

Comment: Coproducts are the most basic kind of colimit. The attaching maps for each of the $n$ 1-cells are maps $\{0, 1\} \to X^0$. For the $k$th 1-cell, the attaching map sends $0$ to the $k$th 0-cell, and sends $1$ to the $(k+1)$st 0-cell (modulo n).

Comment: But the elements of $X^0$ are just points on the sphere right? Can we then say that the attaching maps are just the projections into boundary of $D^1$ into just one point?

Comment: "Projection" isn't quite the right word. $\partial D^1$ is the discrete set $\{0, 1\}$ with 2 elements. You want the attaching map $a\colon\{0,1\}\to X^0$ with $a(0)=(\text{the first endpoint})$ and $a(1) = (\text{the second endpoint})$